# VB.NET - What does ":=" do?

Tags: vb.net, operators

I can't find any information online or under the Operator documentation, but I've seen this ":=" used a few times in VB.NET and I can't work out what it does.

Comment: I would love to see some example code of it's use that was too complex for you to be able to work it out ;-)

Answer (score 10):

It's used for [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51wfzyw0.aspx) (ht to SLaks for the link) in a method call and is usually used with optional arguments.

It's usually useful for calling Word or Excel methods through ActiveX calls, where there are an awful lot of optional arguments, most of which are never used.

Example

```
Private Function test(arg1 As Integer, arg2 As Integer) As Boolean
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", arg1, arg2)
    Return True
End Function
```

These two will both produce the same result

```
test(arg2:=2, arg1:=1)

test(1, 2)
```

Debug output

```
1  2

1  2
```

Answer (score 5):

This is used for [named parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51wfzyw0.aspx):

```
MyMethod(parameterName := value)
```

Comment: Oh that's cool, I didn't even know you could supply the name of the parameter when you called the Sub - I thought the only way to do it was MyMethod(value, value2, , optionalvalue2) etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is to use "named parameters", so you can use parameters in a function in any order, telling the function the name of each one. :)